# Why does the setter of a VB.NET property require a typed argument and why is it ByVal?

Tags: c#, vb.net

In C#, a property's setter `value` keyword will automatically be same as the property's type.

For example, in C# ,type of `value` is `string`

```
private string str = string.Empty;
public string MyText 
{
    get { return str; }
    set { str = value; }
}
```

If we convert this snippet to VB.Net we get

```
Private str As String = String.Empty
Public Property MyText() As String
    Get
        Return str 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        str = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**Questions**

1. Why does set have this line `Set(ByVal value As String)`? Shouldn't value type
   automatically be String. This way.

   ```
   Private str As String = String.Empty
   Public Property MyText() As String
       Get
           Return str 
       End Get
       Set
           str = value
       End Set
   End Property
   ```

   What's the use of that?
2. I cannot change `BYVal` to `ByRef` (I tried, it gives error), then what's use of that also?

Comment: Good question, not sure why it was given a -1 straight off the bat.

Comment: @AlastairPitts: Probably because of the confusing title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *can omit* the `(ByVal value As String)` part. Visual Studio will keep adding it, but it is not required by either the language nor the compiler.

You can use a parameter name other than `value`. Also note that since VS2010 SP1, you can omit the `ByVal` keyword.

---

**Example:**

```
Class Test

    Private str As String = String.Empty

    Public Property MyText() As String
        Get
            Return str 
        End Get
        Set
            str = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property MyText2() As String
        Get
            Return str 
        End Get
        Set(something As String)
            str = something
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Hey if I delete it, as you said, Visual Studio automatically adds it.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal - that the VS editor insisting on adding it (similarly it will add back `ByVal` if you remove it). But the Visual Basic *language* doesn't require these things.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal It doesn't mean that the compiler needs it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever *(similarly it will add back ByVal if you remove it)*: It won't do this anymore since VS2010 SP1.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus - ah. When we started using VS2010, we started migrating from VB -> C# for new development, so I'm using it less and less with the newer VSs

Comment: Nor do I, so I've +1ed it. I've added the relevant quotes from the VB language spec to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think, its part of the syntax in Visual basic. You can omit the data type , if `OptionStrict` is not on. But if you specify the type, it must be same as of property type.

[From MSDN - Set Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b85bc00.aspx)

> *datatype*
>   Required if Option Strict is On. Data type of the value parameter. The
>   data type specified **must be the same as the data type** of the property
>   where this Set statement is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Because you *are* allowed in VB to change the *name* of the parameter:

```
Public Property MyText() As String
    Get
        Return str
    End Get
    Set(ByVal val As String)
        str = val
    End Set
End Property
```

You can't change the `ByVal` to `ByRef` because property parameters can only ever be passed by value. But VB sometimes favours stating facts that are unalterable.

The developers *could* (in theory) have let you just have:

```
Set(val)
```

Because nothing else is alterable. But they opted to make the parameters for properties resembles the parameters for `Function`s and `Sub`s.

---

In fact, you don't *have* to specify the parameter at all. Per the VB language spec (9.7.2):

> If a parameter list is specified, it must have one member, that member must have no modifiers except `ByVal`, and its type must be the same as the type of the property. The parameter represents the property value being set. If the parameter is omitted, a parameter named `Value` is implicitly declared

And (9.5.2):

> A parameter that does not specify `ByRef` or `ByVal` defaults to `ByVal`.

Answer (score 1):

If the value were ByRef, the Setter would be able to modify the caller's value.  It doesn't make sense to allow a property setter to cause side effects like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could have value be an enum and do a select case on it for instance and set the value that way. You don't have to limit the property's set call to only passing the same value type which is a nice feature